# Calling applet from MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, applet

I need to call a java applet from MVC 3 application.

1.In the view ,I am placing the applet tag:

```
<form action="/Home/FileStorage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<applet code = "applet.AppletDemo.class" 
        archive = "@Url.Content("~/Java/Applets/applet.jar")" + "," + "@Url.Content("~/Java/Applets/commons-codec-1.4.jar")" +","+
            "@Url.Content("~/Java/Applets/commons-io-1.4.jar")" +","+ "@Url.Content("~/Java/Applets/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar")" +","+ "@Url.Content("~/Java/Applets/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar")"
        width = "700" height = "500">
        <param name="tenantID" value="1"/>  
        <param name="userID" value="1"/>
        <param name="siteID" value="1"/>
</applet>
</form>
```

2.I have placed the jar files in the folder `Java/Applets`.

3.But the applet is not getting triggered on going to that View.

Please help me by letting me know the mistake.

Comment: The code seems alright, are you sure the jar files are on the server?

Comment: I have placed it in the UI.Web which is client side

Comment: Take a look at the url created by your `Url.Content`, then manually type it into a browser.  It's possible there is no mime type for Jar or the url is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Although its an ASP.NET answer, considering that ASP.NET is sitting on the same base as ASP.NET MVC, take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764671/is-there-an-easy-way-to-incorporate-a-java-applet-in-an-asp-net-page) successfully answered question.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711909/running-java-applet-in-asp-net-mvc-application?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371059/issue-calling-applet-functions-from-java-script?rq=1) are other sources to look at.

See if that helps & let me know. Thank you