# integrating applet with mvc3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, applet

How to integrate applet with mvc3 in the view.

1.I am placing the applet code in controller

archive = "/Content/Applets/applet.jar"

2.Somehow the applet is not getting loaded.

Is it related to the archive

Comment: In the body of the view i am placing the <applet> tag.

Comment: The archive tag shown above is within the applet tag

Comment: <applet name="">          archive = "../Content/Applets/applet.jar"

</applet> .1.Actually the .jar files I placed in a folder Content/applets.2.The root folder is UI.Web ,when the application is launched the URL will be http://UI.web/Home/FileStorage. 3.I tried giving the path as ../ but somehow the applet is not getting triggered.

Comment: please edit your question, not post this as a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling applet from MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715432/calling-applet-from-mvc-3)